# HOW TO UPDATE 2 TABLES IN STRAPI AT ONE CALL IN VUE.JS

Tags: java, vue.js, strapi

I have 2 tables in strapi USER and BUSINESS and I would like to update the 2 tables at once when someone registers. At the moment my code is only updating the USER table and failing to update the
BUSINESS TABLE. BELOW IS MY CODE:
How do I update multiple tables at once`

```
await this.$strapi.register({
          firstname: this.viewModelPerson.Firstname,
          surname: this.viewModelPerson.Surname,
          username: this.viewModelPerson.username,
          email: this.viewModelPerson.email,
          mobile: this.viewModelPerson.Mobile,
          password: this.viewModelPerson.password,
          companyname: this.viewModelBusiness.Name,
           vatnumber: this.viewModelBusiness.VATNumber,
          discountcode: this.viewModelBusiness.DiscountCode,
        })`
```

Comment: Please remove the shouting from the title and the body (using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want you to help). Also, why is this tagged Java? Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: The same way as in Angular, React and jQuery. A request is done to the backend, the framework that makes it is not important. `$strapi.register` isn't official API, nobody but you knows what happens on your end. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Strapi deals with services/models, not tables.